# How to create object affinity in Apache Ignite?

Tags: memcached, ignite

I am a beginner in Apache Ignite. I have 3 java classes ClassA, ClassB, and ClassC.

```
ClassA{ 
        int idA; //unique
        String stringA; 
        public ClassA(){} 
        public ClassA(int idA,String stringA){ 
                this.idA=idA; 
                this.stringA=stringA; 
        } 
        public int getidA(){ 
                return idA; 
        } 
        public String getstringA(){ 
                return stringA; 
        } 
} 

ClassB{ 
        int idB; //unique
        String stringB; 
        public ClassB(){} 
        public ClassB(int idB,String stringB){ 
                this.idB=idB; 
                this.stringB=stringB; 
        } 
        public int getidB(){ 
                return idB; 
        } 
        public String getstringB(){ 
                return stringB; 
        } 
} 

ClassC{ 
        int idC,idB; //idC unique. idB from ClassB
        String stringC; 
        public ClassC(){} 
        public ClassB(int idB,int idC,String stringC){ 
                this.idB=idB; 
                this.idC=idC; 
                this.stringC=stringC; 
        } 
        public int getidC(){ 
                return idC; 
        } 
        public String getstringC(){ 
                return stringC; 
        } 
}
```

Lemme tell an example. I want ClassA in replicated mode and B & C in partitioned modes. ClassC is related to ClassB. The id of ClassB is present in ClassC (acting like a foreign key). Say, I have 3 nodes, 30 ClassA objects, 30 ClassB objects and 30 ClassC objects. They are distributed in nodes like below;

```
Node 1 => ClassA->30, ClassB->10,ClassC->8 
Node 2 => ClassA->30, ClassB->5,ClassC->3 
Node 3 => ClassA->30, ClassB->15,ClassC->19
```

Objects of ClassC related to ClassB should present in same node. I know that there is some mechanism AffinityKey, but I don't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is collocate Class C with Class B based on ID of Class B. In [Apache Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org) it is called Affinity Collocation and is described in detail here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation

In particular, in your case, you should attach [@AffinityKeyMapped](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/affinity/AffinityKeyMapped.html) annotation to *ClassC.idB* field.

Also, more info on PARTITIONED and REPLICATED caches here:
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes

Once you configure your caches this way, you can also use SQL to query them, including distributed SQL joins. More on SQL here:
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-queries

Comment: Gone through it already. Posted the question because i was not able to resolve it.

Comment: You should attach @AffinityKeyMapped annotation to the ClassC.idB field. Here is the javadoc: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/affinity/AffinityKeyMapped.html